# C++ SFINAE to choose an overload between reference type and argument converted to reference?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, sfinae

Consider:

```
struct BigData {...};

// Let's get a BigData by reference, but use it as a value.
// For example, we may want to make a copy of the object, but we'd
// like to avoid the pass-by-value overhead at the call site.
template <typename T, *some template magic?*>
void processData(T& t) {
    printf("Your BigData was converted to a reference argument.\n");
    ...
}

// Now, we want an overload that will know that there wasn't a
// conversion to reference and will treat it like a reference.
// Perhaps we are adding this BigData to a list of references.
template <typename T, *some template magic?*>
void processData(T& t) {
    printf("You gave me a BigData reference.\n");
    ...
}

int main() {
    BigData data;
    BigData& ref = data;

    processData(data); // "Your BigData was converted to a reference argument."
    processData(ref); // "You gave me a BigData reference."

    return 0;
}
```

In short, my objective is to have overloads that distinguish between where a reference binding came from - either a value of the type or an (already) reference type. I have tried using `std::enable_if` and family in combination with overloads that do and do not take references to `T`, but I can't find a way to accomplish this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are not understanding how reference binding works.  You can not only bind a reference to another reference but also a value that is of value type (i.e. not reference qualified)

So if you want to pass the `BigData` object by reference, you just need to do the following

```
template <typename T>
void processData(T& t) {
    cout << "Your BigData was passed as a reference argument" << endl;
    // ...
}

int main() {
    BigData data;
    BigData& ref = data;

    processData(data); 
    processData(ref);

    return 0;
}
```

Here both the `processData` calls will pass the `BigData` object by reference (i.e. no copies during function invocation).

You don't need to deal with the case where the object being passed to the function is a reference separately from the normal case.  `std::enable_if` is not required here.

Further there is no way to differentiate between the two cases, either using `data` or `ref` as arguments to functions because they are both lvalues.  You will have to do something like the following, if you want to inspect whether the `decltype` of the expression is a reference or not

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_reference<T>::value>* = nullptr>
void processData(std::add_lvalue_reference_t<T>) {
    cout << "You gave me a reference argument." << endl;
}

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_reference<T>::value>* = nullptr>
void processData(std::add_lvalue_reference_t<T>) {
    cout << "Your argument was converted to a reference." << endl;
}

int main() {
    auto integer_value = 1;
    const auto& integer_ref = 2;
    processData<decltype(integer_value)>(integer_value);
    processData<decltype(integer_ref)>(integer_ref);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Right. I understand that, however my objective is to have overloads that distinguish between where the binding came from - either a value of the type or a (already) reference type.

Comment: @BrandonKammerdiener take a look at the updated answer

Comment: Thanks. This is about as far as I got as well, but ideally I'd like to avoid modifying the call. I appreciate your help!